# image stretched on 8 inch tablet

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview

I designed a layout which contains rows of buttons and these buttons have background .I tested this layout in different devices and it works fine ,even in 8 inch tablet and 'Youwave' emulator. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3" >


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_die"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_die" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_logo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_logo" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/veladat"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/veladat" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_ezde"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_ezde" />
                          <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_faaliat"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_faaliat" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3" >


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_havades"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/havades" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_zendeg"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_zendeg" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3" >

                     <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_favlist"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_favlist" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_shakh"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/shakhsiat" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                            android:src="@drawable/site" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

and this is a part of  picture of YouWave emulator:

what is the problem with my code?

Comment: can use  android:src=""  instead of  "android:background" ..Give it a try don't know if it fixes your problem

Comment: Please check my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Just add **`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`** in your ImageView

**Note:**

You can use **ImageView instead Button**

```
                 <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds=true
                        android:src="@drawable/site" />
```

If not working then add **android:scaleType**

Second Way, You can use **ImageButton**
and add `android:src="@drawable/` instead `android:background`

Comment: I do not want to use image button .is there any solution to use button ?

Comment: @serenei I had faced same problem . I use ImageView

Comment: @serenei if your background is a image then button use as ImageView